# Reveal modal doesn't work when included by Interchange

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

Interesting issue with Reveal modals in Foundation (5.3.2)

When including another file (Using Interchange or plain Ajax) that contains a Reveal link/modal, the modal does not display on click of the link. No errors thrown.

I have tried various forms of '$(document).foundation("reflow")' to no effect.

Strangely, what does seem to work is if I include this anywhere in the parent page:

```
<div data-reveal></div>
```

No other parameters required.  If the parent page contains that, the Reveal modal works perfectly from the ajax-included file.

Not sure if this is a bug in Foundation, or if I'm just missing something important.  Thanks for any advice.